# aws lambda python package from existing installation

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, digital-ocean

i have already installed many python libs in digital ocean's vps. How do i import all of the installed packages from digital ocean vps to aws lambda?
in below link,
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html
steps are given to install python libs using --target and zip them. but my requirement is not to install packages again in lambda. just want to import all the installed packages from digital ocean.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the [venv portion](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html#python-package-venv) of the documentation (or use conda). Just as you used `pip` to download packages in digital ocean, use it again in amazon.

If you forget what you downloaded and didn't write it down in a `requirements.txt` or `environment.yml` file, then `pip list` will jog your memory.

Comment: so i believe creating new setup and installing all packages again is the only way. thanks for reply